# How can I make a table in php that varies in terms of columns

Tags: php

I have a php table that ideally have 13 rows and 9 columns. It has been created from text file given by shell script. It varies after 2 minutes and problem is sometimes last 2,3 rows do not have 9 columns, their columns go unaligned with headers. Columns go to left. Is there a way to create a table which should preserve column place even if its front column is missing

```
file_get_contents('/c:/personal/data') or die ("Unable")));
//$length = count($new_array);
    //print_r($new_array)
$table1 = '<table class = "table table-hover" >';
$trimmed = trim($myfile);
$filearray = explode("\n", $trimmed);


foreach($filearray as $row) {
$table1 .= '<tr>';  
// here separate your row that is a string, into an array
$cols = explode(" ", $row); 


 foreach($cols as $value) {

    $table1 .= '<td style = "text-align: left" >'.$value.'</td>';
}
$table1 .= '</tr>';
```

}
    $table1 .= '';

```
echo $table1;
```

Comment: `$table1 .= '';` - what is this code for? :)

Comment: Well, to add nothing at all, obviously.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the row exists and if not insert an empty cell, like this:

```
...
foreach($filearray as $row) {
    $table1 .= '<tr>';  
    // here separate your row that is a string, into an array
    $cols = explode(" ", $row); 
    for ($i=0; $i < 9; $i++){
        if (isset($cols[$i]))
            $table1 .= '<td style = "text-align: left" >'.$value.'</td>';
        else
            $table1 .= '<td style = "text-align: left" ></td>'; 
    }
    $table1 .= '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> problem is sometimes last 2,3 rows do not have 9 columns, their
>   columns go unaligned with headers

You need to check, that number of real columns is equal to ideal number. If it is less - add empty columns:

```
$ideal = 9;
$n = count($cols);
if($n < $ideal)
{
    for ($i = $n; $i < $ideal; ++$i)
    {
        $cols[$i] = '';
    }
}
```